# Subsonic: How to exclude a table column so that its not included in the generated SQL query

Tags: sql, subsonic

I need to insert a record to a table.

Subsonic builds the query something like this (as far as i know):

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(Title, Description, RowVersion)
VALUES 
(@Title, @Description, @RowVersion)
```

But i want to remove the RowVersion column from the SQL query bacause its autogenerated by the sql server.
How can i do that?

Comment: I've updated answer, please have a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this. SubSonic is intelligent enough to handle this!

Just create new object assign values to properties and save it.

```
var o = new DataObject();
o.Name="Foo";
o.Age = 20;
//o.RowVersion = ....; DON'T ASSIGN THIS
o.Save();
```

EDIT:- Here is what I've tried:

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTimeStamp](
[RowID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL
)
```

Code:

```
private static void Test()
{
    var o = new TestTimeStamp();
    o.Description = "Hello World";
    o.Save();
}
```

**FIXED**:- Yippe, I spinned my head over the cause, as this has never happened in SubSonic 2. I branched SubSonic 3 code, but there was not anything to find. Then after much fooling around I once again examined T4 templates. Some how the `IsReadOnly` property is not being set but it is checked when cretaing insert, update queries in SubSonic.Extension.Object.cs class. So the solution is to add a line to `Structs.tt` file's `for` loop which adds columns to table classes :) . To fix find the following loop (it starts at line 30)

```
<# foreach(var col in tbl.Columns){#>
       Columns.Add(new DatabaseColumn("<#=col.Name#>", this)
       {
```

and change initialization of new DatabaseColumn to as follows:

```
   Columns.Add(new DatabaseColumn("<#=col.Name#>", this)
   {
       IsPrimaryKey = <#=col.IsPK.ToString().ToLower()#>,
       DataType = DbType.<#=col.DbType.ToString()#>,
       IsNullable = <#=col.IsNullable.ToString().ToLower()#>,
       AutoIncrement = <#=col.AutoIncrement.ToString().ToLower()#>,
       IsForeignKey = <#=col.IsForeignKey.ToString().ToLower()#>,

       //THIS LINE DO THE TRICK.
       IsReadOnly = <#=col.DataType.ToLower().Equals("timestamp")
                          .ToString().ToLower() #>
   });
```

PS:- Please get subsonic srouce from [here](http://github.com/amantur/SubSonic-3.0). In the previous version only null and `AutoIncrement` is checked on inclusion into Add and Update column list, but this code checks for ReadOnly property also.

Comment: that is not working..
RowVersion is a required field..
the RowVersion is a timestamp column..

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Is row version of type timestamp?

Comment: think you are using SubSonic 3!

Comment: still not working man.. is there anything i should change aside from Structs.tt?

Answer (score 0):

I was having grief with timestamp fields so just excluded timestamp columns in Structs.tt altogether. Same place as above Line 30. This is using current SubSonic 3.0 master checkout

```
if(<#=col.DataType.ToLower().Equals("timestamp").ToString().ToLower() #>)
{}else{
 Columns.Add(new DatabaseColumn("<#=col.Name#>", this)
 {
      IsPrimaryKey = <#=col.IsPK.ToString().ToLower()#>,
      DataType = DbType.<#=col.DbType.ToString()#>,
      IsNullable = <#=col.IsNullable.ToString().ToLower()#>,
      AutoIncrement = <#=col.AutoIncrement.ToString().ToLower()#>,
      IsForeignKey = <#=col.IsForeignKey.ToString().ToLower()#>,
      MaxLength = <#=col.MaxLength#>
 });
}
```