# subsonic timestamp issue on insert record

Tags: subsonic, timestamp

My problem is about the timestamp column in one of my database tables. This field is required because sqlserver automatically generates it. Since this column is required subsonic included it in the insert query..

im using subsonic 3.0

`info.Save();`

error message:

`Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following answer for a workaround for this:

[Subsonic: How to exclude a table column so that its not included in the generated SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552763/subsonic-how-to-exclude-a-table-column-so-that-its-not-included-in-the-generated/1552836#1552836)